# array function some not working as expected? What is wrong in my code?

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs

```
 const priceType = ['monthly', 'annual'];
 var discounts =[
                    {product: "A", monthlyDiscount : 15.0, monthlyMaxDiscount: 30.0, annualDiscount : 25.0, annualMaxDiscount : 20.0},
                    {product: "B", monthlyDiscount : 5.0, monthlyMaxDiscount: 20.0, annualDiscount : 40.0, annualMaxDiscount : 30.0}
                ]
                
 var exceedsDiscount;
```

If any of my discount objects exceeds max discount I need to set the Boolean as true and stop checking other array items.

I used for loops and this works as expected :

```
 exceedsDiscount = false;
 angular.forEach(priceType, function(type){
       angular.forEach(discounts, function(discount){
           if(discount[`${type}Discount`] > discount[`${type}MaxDiscount`]){
               exceedsDiscount = true;
               return; 
           }

    });
```

If I try to use the every and some arrow functions the outcome is **not** same. It randomly gives true or false. Any idea how I can do using without using two for loops?

```
exceedsDiscount = false;
    exceedsDiscount = priceType.every(type => discounts.some(discount =>{return discount[`${type}Discount`] > discount[`${type}MaxDiscount`];}));
```

Comment: Your first logic would correspond to `some(... some(`, not `every(... some(`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As noted by [trincot](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5459839/trincot) in the comment, instead of `.every(.... .some(...))`, if one uses `.some(... .some(...))` - the required result is obtained.

By `'some .. some'` we refer to a scenario that there is "some" type for which there is "some" discount which is greater than maxDiscount.

Snippet below:

```js
const priceType = ['monthly', 'annual'];
var discounts = [{
    product: "A",
    monthlyDiscount: 15.0,
    monthlyMaxDiscount: 30.0,
    annualDiscount: 25.0,
    annualMaxDiscount: 20.0
  },
  {
    product: "B",
    monthlyDiscount: 5.0,
    monthlyMaxDiscount: 20.0,
    annualDiscount: 40.0,
    annualMaxDiscount: 30.0
  }
];

const everySome = priceType.every(type => discounts.some(discount =>{return discount[`${type}Discount`] > discount[`${type}MaxDiscount`];}));;

const someSome = priceType.some(type => discounts.some(discount =>{return discount[`${type}Discount`] > discount[`${type}MaxDiscount`];}));

console.log(
  '\n.every(.. .some( returns: ', JSON.stringify(everySome),
  '\n.some(.. .some(  returns: ', JSON.stringify(someSome)
);
```

Comment: Non related: the JSON on your profile page is not valid. You might want to improve on that ;-)

Comment: I just created a sample data while writing question.. Thanks :)

Comment: @trincot - got it. I just tried `JSON.parse` on my `me.json` and it failed. Fixed it with double-quote and wrapping it in ``back-ticks` `` and it worked. Now, just need update back to my profile. Thank you for sharing. :-)